# Understanding memory leak with C++ extension for python

Tags: python, c++, memory-management, python-extensions

I have been struggling to understand what I am doing wrong with the memory management of this this C++ function for a python module, but I don't have much experience in this regard.

Every time I run this function, the memory consumption of the python interpreter increases. The function is supposed to take in two numpy arrays and create  new numpy arrays with the desired output.

```
extern "C" PyObject *radec_to_xyz(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    // Parse the input arguments
    PyArrayObject *ra_arrobj, *dec_arrobj;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!O!", &PyArray_Type, &ra_arrobj, &PyArray_Type, &dec_arrobj)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "invalid arguments, expected two numpy arrays");
        return nullptr;
    }
    // skipping checks that would ensure:
    // dtype==float64, dim==1, len()>0 and equal for inputs, data or contiguous
    npy_intp size = PyArray_SIZE(ra_arrobj);

    // create the output numpy array with the same size and datatype
    PyObject *x_obj = PyArray_EMPTY(1, &size, NPY_FLOAT64, 0);
    if (!x_obj) return nullptr;
    Py_XINCREF(x_obj);

    // get pointers to the arrays
    double *ra_array = static_cast<double *>(PyArray_DATA(ra_arrobj));
    double *dec_array = static_cast<double *>(PyArray_DATA(dec_arrobj));
    double *x_array = static_cast<double *>(PyArray_DATA(reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(x_obj)));

    // compute the new coordinates
    for (npy_intp i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        double cos_ra = cos(ra_array[i]);
        double cos_dec = cos(dec_array[i]);
        // compute final coordinates
        x_array[i] = cos_ra * cos_dec;
    }
    // return the arrays holding the new coordinates
    return Py_BuildValue("O", x_obj);
}
```

I suspect that I am getting the reference counts wrong and therefore, the returned numpy arrays don't get garbage collected. I tried changing the reference counts, but this did not help.

When I pass the X array as additional argument from the python interpreter instead of allocating it in the function, the memory leak is gone as expected.

Comment: How do you measure that memory consumption increases?

Comment: The python process hogs a few gigabytes of data when I run this with a few million objects, increasing every time. The same does not happen with the pure numpy version of the function.

Comment: Could you reduce the code some (cf. [mre])? If you hardcode the input, you should be able to get rid of error checks, and it should be possible to drop computing coordinates without affecting memory consumption. How about dropping the "y" and "z" parts to focus on "x"? That might reduce the leak to a third, but it's still a leak, so good enough for this question.

Comment: I simplified the code as suggested.
Interestingly, the problem is gone when I allocate the arrays outside of the C function and pass them in as arguments.

Comment: OK, if the problem is gone in your simplified version, now incrementally add back the code until the issue returns.

Comment: why are you using a `Py_XINCREF` in there ? functions that return a new object should return it with a refcount of 1, you don't have to increment it unless you are storing it somewhere else.

Comment: `Py_BuildValue` also increments the refcount, so you should decref after you create the returned object with `Py_BuildValue` ... it is not needed here anyway, just return `x_obj`.

Comment: Thank you so much for these comments, I was not aware of that, especially the increment through the build value. By removing the INCREF and adding the DECREFs for x, I was able to fix the memory leak.
The reason for the BuildValue is that the function will return a tuple once it is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Py_XINCREF(x_obj)` is not needed because `Py_BuildValue("O", x_obj)` will increment the reference count for you. In other words, you're accidentally increasing the reference count too much by 1

Comment: Thank you so much, I was not aware of this and that fixed my issue.